# arduino nano avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: upload, arduino, avrdude

I am trying to upload the blink sketch to a new arduino nano v3 (technically it is the iduino knockoff from geeetech) with atmega328 but I keep getting the infamous "avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00" error... How can I avoid this error and get a successful upload?
Here is what I know:

- 1) I have installed the ftdi drivers according to the ftdi
  instructions on the nano.
- 2) In the arduino IDE it recognizes the
  com port. I have both correct port and correct board selected.
- 3) I shorted my Rx and Tx together and typed a string into my serial
  monitor and received it back as I should have.
- 4) When I attempt to upload the blink sketch my L led flashes, the Rx pin blinks 3 times,
  and then I get the error message and the modified version of the
  sketch (I just extended the delay) doesn't go through.
- 5) This piece of information might be inconsequential but my nano is in a perpetual
  state of blinking as if it had let me upload the sketch once... I did
  try to upload the sketch before I installed the drivers.

I think that is all the relevant information but ask away if it is not. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully I found that it was a simple dumb fix after all. I got out the magnifying glass and upon close inspection of my chip discovered that it was an atmega168 and not an atmega328 like I had originally thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

funny coincidence, i found [this article](http://hackaday.com/2014/11/22/solving-arduinos-stk500_getsync-error/) in hackaday.com:

> "Frustrated with one of the greatest failures to become an Arduino
>   tinkerer, [psgarcha] took a good,       long look at the Uno board. He
>   glanced over to an Arduino Mega board. Something looked different. On
>   the Uno, the resonator had blown off. Problem found, at least."
>   [link](http://hackaday.com/2014/11/22/solving-arduinos-stk500_getsync-error/)

Hope your resonator didn't blew off.

Comment: I have actually been having this same issue with 2 identical boards so the chances of that being the case are slim if both are having the same issue. The hardware on both looks sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually on windows platform  this error is very often the only solution is to  reinstall arduino driver

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Bhash Freeduino`, what worked for me was

1. The `Pro and Pro mini` setting
2. AtMeta328
3. /dev/ttyUSB0